# Identify source of change to trigger

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, database-trigger, audit-trail

The application I work on has an audit function which woks by setting SQL triggers on certain fields. When a change is detected, the trigger fires and adds a row to an audit table indicating what field changed, type of change (update, insert, or delete) key value for changed field, and before & after values. However, changes can be made by various program modules, and i want to track which module or sub-module made a particular change. this is a multi-user concurrent application, so different users (or scripts) may be running different modules, or different instances of the same module, at the same time. Locking prevents different users from changing the same record at the same time, and is working properly.

Here is the existing trigger for one table on updates. The triggers for insert and delete, and on a second table, are all quite similar. (table and field names have been changed)

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[APP_trg_AU_Ptbl1]
on [dbo].[Ptbl1] for update as
declare @ct int, @now datetime, @id int

select @ct = @@rowcount
if @ct = 0 return

select @id = s.user_identity
  from SpidUser s inner join master..sysprocesses m
  on m.spid = s.spid and m.login_time = s.login_time
  where m.spid = @@SPID
select @id = isnull(@id, 0)
select @now = getdate()

insert AuditTbl(edit_time, edit_type, useridentity, table_name,
field_name, old_value, new_value, _fk_table, _fk_person, _fk_event)

select @now, convert(char(1),'U'), @id, 'Ptbl1',
convert(varchar(255), 'item_code'), convert(varchar(255),
deleted.item_code), convert(varchar(255), _src.item_code),
convert(int, _src._pk), convert(int, EVENT.person_id), convert(int,
EVENT.EVENT_id)
FROM deleted INNER JOIN inserted AS _src ON deleted._pk=_src._pk INNER JOIN
EVENT ON _src._fk_event=EVENT.EVENT_id
WHERE 1 = CASE
  WHEN _src.item_code is null THEN 
    CASE WHEN deleted.item_code is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  ELSE CASE WHEN deleted.item_code is null THEN 1
    ELSE CASE WHEN _src.item_code = deleted.item_code THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  END
END

UNION ALL select @now, convert(char(1),'U'), @id, 'Ptbl1',
'item_sequence_num', convert(varchar(255), deleted.item_sequence_num),
convert(varchar(255), _src.item_sequence_num), _src._pk, EVENT.person_id,
EVENT.EVENT_id
FROM deleted INNER JOIN inserted AS _src ON deleted._pk=_src._pk INNER JOIN
EVENT ON _src._fk_event=EVENT.EVENT_id
WHERE 1 = CASE
  WHEN _src.item_sequence_num is null THEN 
    CASE WHEN deleted.item_sequence_num is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  ELSE CASE WHEN deleted.item_sequence_num is null THEN 1
    ELSE CASE WHEN _src.item_sequence_num = deleted.item_sequence_num THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  END
END
```

I want to be able to set a string that identifies the currently active module, so that the trigger would be able to pick it up and include it when adding a record to the audit table. I can't lock a table/field combo that everyone will write to, as that would serialize all DB access and  destroy concurrency and thus performance. I am not sure where I can put or expose the string so that the trigger can reliably associate it with the specific change that caused the trigger to fire.

Client sites use a mix of SQL-server 2005, 2008, and 2012, so any code must work in all of these.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” question and it’s too broad to give a specific technical answer, making it off-topic here on Stack Overflow. You’ll need to attempt to solve this problem and show your code so we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level as well as to demonstrate your commitment to solving this problem.

If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: Triggers do not get attached to columns, they get attached to tables. The rest of your question is so broad it is not answerable. And keep in mind that sql server does not care what called it, only that it was called. It is unaware of the process that executed an update.

Comment: I can list some things that didn't work, mostly because the trigger does not reliably run in the same thread that the db save does. Thus using @@identity ddn't help. I am looking for any object or kind of object which I can set, and which can be set separately for each active db session, and which the trigger code can read. Trigger code is, i know, limited in what it can access.

Comment: "And keep in mind that sql server does not care what called it, only that it was called. It is unaware of the process that executed an update" That is really my problem -- I want to be able to make it aware, in effect. I will create a redacted version of one of the current triggers, to help illustrate the issue on a more technical level. I'm not allowed to post unaltered application code.

Comment: You can't "make it aware of what called it". You could add some metadata to the connection string like ApplicationName which you can retrieve in a query. But it would require adding that to every single connection string in all the applications that connect so you know where the call came from.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, more exactly i want to provide metadata that the caller can alter and the trigger code can read. I can see that the connection string is one place to provide such, and i also see that it would need to be done with every connection to be at all comprehensive. Are there othe places where such metadata could be stored?